# Recover erroneously deleted Oauth from the openshift

Tags: openshift

Due to a mistake, I accidentally deleted OAuth from my OpenShift cluster. How can I recreate it?

I attempted to delete all authentication-related pods, but they still weren't created automatically.

Does anyone have a YAML file that I can use as to create?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default `OAuth` resource is just an empty manifest, like this:

```
apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1
kind: OAuth
metadata:
  name: cluster
spec: {}
```

(Extracted from [the documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.10/authentication/configuring-internal-oauth.html)).

According to `kubectl explain oauth`, there are no required fields in the `spec` property:

```
$ kubectl explain oauth.spec
KIND:     OAuth
VERSION:  config.openshift.io/v1

RESOURCE: spec <Object>

DESCRIPTION:
     spec holds user settable values for configuration

FIELDS:
   identityProviders    <[]Object>
     identityProviders is an ordered list of ways for a user to identify
     themselves. When this list is empty, no identities are provisioned for
     users.

   templates    <Object>
     templates allow you to customize pages like the login page.

   tokenConfig  <Object>
     tokenConfig contains options for authorization and access tokens
```

You only need to set any of those fields if you are customizing the oauth configuration (e.g., by adding a custom provider).

Comment: The server doesn't have a resource type "kind: OAuth, apiVersion: config.openshift.io/v1".

i am not able to create that one due to the don't have OAuth

Comment: If you run `kubectl api-resources | grep oauths`, what do you see?